# How to get the value of the attribute of element in angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-directives

I have an HTML span, which has two hyperlinks.

```html
<span><a href="http://appcarvers.cloudaccess.host/index.php?Itemid=207" alt="Shirley Setia">Shirley Setia</a><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
<a href="http://appcarvers.cloudaccess.host/index.php?Itemid=210" alt="Harry">Harry</a>
</span>
```

I have created one angular directive. Which reads the DOM element and the href link. But it only reads the first href only how do I read the second href from the above span so that I can parse it.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[stream-link]' // Attribute selector
})

export class StreamLink {
  constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {

    renderer.listen(element.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {

      let anchorUrl = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('a');
      // This anchorUrl shows only first href url
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try using @ContentChildren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where on your template are you calling the directive? Is it directly on the `<span>` element or is it on a higher level?

The `querySelector` API only selects the first instance of a html node given a selector, so if you're applying the directive directly on the `<span>`, there should be no problem with your current implementation cause basically there's just one `<a>`tag inside the `<span>`.

If the directive is hosting multiple span tags like:

```
<div stream-link>
  <span><a href="...">Link 1</a></span>
  <span><a href="...">Link 2</a></span>
  <span><a href="...">Link 3</a></span>
</div>
```

You should use `querySelectorAll` instead, and that would select all nodes that are nested inside your directive element.

**Update:**

The output of `this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a')` is a NodeList which has the `forEach` array method built in. Just iterate over the list and get the `href` property of each element.

```
let urls = [];
let nodes = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
nodes.forEach(node => urls.push(node.href));
```

Comment: I have tried this `this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a')` but it tells the only number of anchors and activated anchor but doesn't show actual URL of the anchor.